using clang PPCallbacks to expand and rewrite macros
I need help with writing an instrumentation application that expands 'C' macros and forwards the expanded token text to a RecursiveASTVisitor<MyASTVisitor> to rewrite various statement types.
EDITS TO ORIGINAL QUESTION
I updated and simplified the entire application (removing the unneessary clang::PPCallbacks class).  I also isolated the problem to a few lines of code in the MyFrontEndAction::ExecuteAction - see comments below for details.
// ExecuteAction is called to perform the main action of the frontend.
// First, it preprocesses the input code, then it creates a new
// CompilerInstance to parse the preprocessed code, and outputs the
// rewritten code.
void ExecuteAction() override {
    auto &PP = getCompilerInstance().getPreprocessor();
    PP.PrintStats();

    // use preprocessor options to minimize changes to the code.
    // in particular, we need to preserve blank lines, comments
    // and fully recursive macro expansions.
    clang::PreprocessorOutputOptions PPO;
    PPO.ShowCPP = true;                 // Print normal preprocessed output.
    PPO.ShowComments = true;            // Show comments.
    PPO.ShowLineMarkers = true;         // Show #line markers. (keep blank lines)
    PPO.UseLineDirectives = true;       // Use #line instead of GCC-style # N.
    PPO.ShowMacroComments = true;       // Show comments, even in macros.
    PPO.ShowMacros = true;              // Print macro definitions.
    PPO.ShowIncludeDirectives = false;  // Print includes, imports etc. within preprocessed output.
    PPO.RewriteIncludes = false;        // Preprocess include directives only.
    PPO.RewriteImports  = false;        // Include contents of transitively-imported modules.
    PPO.MinimizeWhitespace = false;     // Ignore whitespace from input.
    PPO.DirectivesOnly = false;         // Process directives but do not expand macros.
    PPO.KeepSystemIncludes = true;      // Do not expand system headers.

    // Preprocess the input code and store it in a string.
    std::string PreprocessedCode;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream OS(PreprocessedCode);
    clang::DoPrintPreprocessedInput(PP, &OS, PPO);
    OS.flush();

    // Filter out #line markers using std::ranges
    std::istringstream inputStream(PreprocessedCode);
    std::ostringstream tempStream;

    // gcc or msvc line markers supported
    static std::regex gLineMarkerPattern(
        R"(^#\s*(line\s*)?\d+\s+\"[^\"]+\".*)");

    // strip leading line markers - much easier to recognize the GCC format
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inputStream, line)) {
        if (!std::regex_match(line, gLineMarkerPattern)) {
            tempStream << line << "\n";
            llvm::outs() << line << "\n";
        } else {
            llvm::outs() << "removed: " << line << "\n";
        }
    }

    // Create a memory buffer from the preprocessed code
    auto Buffer = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(
        tempStream.str(), "<preprocessed>");

    // Create a new CompilerInstance to parse the memory buffer
    clang::CompilerInstance CI;
    CI.createDiagnostics();

    // Set up target options for the new CompilerInstance.
    const auto TargetOpts = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    TargetOpts->Triple = llvm::Triple::normalize(
        llvm::sys::getProcessTriple());
    CI.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(
        CI.getDiagnostics(), TargetOpts));

    // Create file manager and source manager for the new CompilerInstance.
    CI.createFileManager();
    CI.createSourceManager(CI.getFileManager());

    // Create a file ID for the memory buffer and set it as the main file.
    const auto FileID = CI.getSourceManager().createFileID(std::move(Buffer));
    CI.getSourceManager().setMainFileID(FileID);

    // Create a freshly minted preprocessor for the entire
    // translation unit and enter the main source file.
    CI.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
    CI.getPreprocessor().EnterMainSourceFile();
    CI.createASTContext();

    // Parse the AST from the preprocessed code.
    // This should initiate the Visitor callbacks
    // to rewrite the preprocessed code.
    // =====================================================
    // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP: THE FOLLOWING CALL RAISES
    // A PREPROCESSOR ASSERTION ERROR WHEN UNDER THE COVERS
    // IT CALLS 'Preprocessor::EnterMainSourceFile()'
    // assert(NumEnteredSourceFiles == 0 &&
    //    "Cannot reenter the main file!");
    // AT THIS TIME NumEnteredSourceFiles is 2.
    // =====================================================
    ParseAST(CI.getPreprocessor(),
        nullptr, CI.getASTContext());

    // Output the final rewritten code
    if (const clang::RewriteBuffer *RewriteBuf =
        Rewriter.getRewriteBufferFor(CI.getSourceManager().getMainFileID())) {
        llvm::outs() << std::string(RewriteBuf->begin(), RewriteBuf->end());
    }
}

Input test C file
Consider the following 'C' code containing a number of test macros.  The file name is: c:\temp\test2.c.
I am particularly interested in expanding nested function-like macros.
#include <stdio.h>

#define TWO                     (2)         // object like macro
#define THREE()                 (3)         // function like macro with 0 args
#define FOUR()                  (4)         // function like macro with 0 args
#define NUMSQUARED(x)           ((x)*(x))   // function like macro with 1 arg
#define MIN(a, b)               (((a) <= (b/*COMMENTb1*/)) ? (a) : (b/*COMMENTb2*/))
#define MAX(a, b)               (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define FUNC_MACRO(x)           ((x) + 1)
#define NESTED_MACRO(a, b)      (FUNC_MACRO(a) + NUMSQUARED(b) + FUNC_MACRO(FOUR()) + TWO + THREE())
#define DEFINE_FUNC(name)   \
int name(int val) {         \
    int v1 = val + 1;       \
    return v1;              \
}

// stamp out 'macroFooFn' functionDecl.
DEFINE_FUNC(macroFooFn)

// stamp out 'macroBarFn(..)' functionDecl.
DEFINE_FUNC(macroBarFn)

/* Main function comment */
int main() {
    // test1
    int a = NESTED_MACRO(1, 2);

    // test2
    int b = MIN(1, TWO); // trailing comment

    // test3
    int c = MIN(1, 2);

    // test4
    int d = MIN(1, THREE());

    // test5
    int f = MIN(1, NUMSQUARED(3));

    // test6
    int g = MIN(MAX(1, 2), 3);

    // test7
    int h = (a > 3) ? 4 : 5 /*comment*/;

    // test functionDecl macro expansion
    int nine = macroFooFn(8);

    // test functionDecl macro expansion
    int ten = macroBarFn(9);

    // return from main.
    return 1;
}

The problem
I need to write a libTooling application that expands preprocessed tokens and then forwards the preprocessed tokens (in the form of either a temporary file or memory buffer) to a RecursiveASTVisitor for rewriting various statement types.
Partial Solution
By extending a clang::ASTFrontendAction, I was able to produce similar output to clang -E using a very simple stripped down libTooling application.
In my overloaded ExecuteAction(), I added a some printing options to ensure that the preprocessor produces expanded macros with comments intact.
This works well and avoids the necessity of creating a clang::PPCallbacks subclass where I would need to overrie the PPCallbacks::MacroExpands method to handle the individual token expansions.
The problem I am facing is when I call clang::ParseAST(..) below (see details in the comments).  This is where I need help.
// ExecuteAction is called to perform the main action of the frontend.
// First, it preprocesses the input code, then it creates a new
// CompilerInstance to parse the preprocessed code, and outputs the
// rewritten code.
void ExecuteAction() override {
    auto &PP = getCompilerInstance().getPreprocessor();
    PP.PrintStats();

    // use preprocessor options to minimize changes to the code.
    // in particular, we need to preserve blank lines, comments
    // and fully recursive macro expansions.
    clang::PreprocessorOutputOptions PPO;
    PPO.ShowCPP = true;                 // Print normal preprocessed output.
    PPO.ShowComments = true;            // Show comments.
    PPO.ShowLineMarkers = true;         // Show #line markers. (keep blank lines)
    PPO.UseLineDirectives = true;       // Use #line instead of GCC-style # N.
    PPO.ShowMacroComments = true;       // Show comments, even in macros.
    PPO.ShowMacros = true;              // Print macro definitions.
    PPO.ShowIncludeDirectives = false;  // Print includes, imports etc. within preprocessed output.
    PPO.RewriteIncludes = false;        // Preprocess include directives only.
    PPO.RewriteImports  = false;        // Include contents of transitively-imported modules.
    PPO.MinimizeWhitespace = false;     // Ignore whitespace from input.
    PPO.DirectivesOnly = false;         // Process directives but do not expand macros.
    PPO.KeepSystemIncludes = true;      // Do not expand system headers.

    // Preprocess the input code and store it in a string.
    std::string PreprocessedCode;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream OS(PreprocessedCode);
    clang::DoPrintPreprocessedInput(PP, &OS, PPO);
    OS.flush();

    // Filter out #line markers using std::ranges
    std::istringstream inputStream(PreprocessedCode);
    std::ostringstream tempStream;

    // gcc or msvc line markers supported
    static std::regex gLineMarkerPattern(
        R"(^#\s*(line\s*)?\d+\s+\"[^\"]+\".*)");

    // strip leading line markers - much easier to recognize the GCC format
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inputStream, line)) {
        if (!std::regex_match(line, gLineMarkerPattern)) {
            tempStream << line << "\n";
            llvm::outs() << line << "\n";
        } else {
            llvm::outs() << "removed: " << line << "\n";
        }
    }

    // Create a memory buffer from the preprocessed code
    auto Buffer = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(
        tempStream.str(), "<preprocessed>");

    // Create a new CompilerInstance to parse the memory buffer
    clang::CompilerInstance CI;
    CI.createDiagnostics();

    // Set up target options for the new CompilerInstance.
    const auto TargetOpts = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    TargetOpts->Triple = llvm::Triple::normalize(
        llvm::sys::getProcessTriple());
    CI.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(
        CI.getDiagnostics(), TargetOpts));

    // Create file manager and source manager for the new CompilerInstance.
    CI.createFileManager();
    CI.createSourceManager(CI.getFileManager());

    // Create a file ID for the memory buffer and set it as the main file.
    const auto FileID = CI.getSourceManager().createFileID(std::move(Buffer));
    CI.getSourceManager().setMainFileID(FileID);

    // Create a freshly minted preprocessor for the entire
    // translation unit and enter the main source file.
    CI.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
    CI.getPreprocessor().EnterMainSourceFile();
    CI.createASTContext();

    // Parse the AST from the preprocessed code.
    // This should initiate the Visitor callbacks
    // to rewrite the preprocessed code.
    // =====================================================
    // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP: THE FOLLOWING CALL RAISES
    // A PREPROCESSOR ASSERTION ERROR WHEN UNDER THE COVERS
    // IT CALLS 'Preprocessor::EnterMainSourceFile()'
    // assert(NumEnteredSourceFiles == 0 &&
    //    "Cannot reenter the main file!");
    // AT THIS TIME NumEnteredSourceFiles is 2.
    // =====================================================
    ParseAST(CI.getPreprocessor(),
        nullptr, CI.getASTContext());

    // Output the final rewritten code
    if (const clang::RewriteBuffer *RewriteBuf =
        Rewriter.getRewriteBufferFor(CI.getSourceManager().getMainFileID())) {
        llvm::outs() << std::string(RewriteBuf->begin(), RewriteBuf->end());
    }
}

In the code above, the call to clang::DoPrintPreprocessedInput(PP, &llvm::outs(), PPO) correctly streams the expanded tokens to the console (llvm::outs).  Unfortunately after those lines, I do not know how to get this raw text stream output and forward it to the TernaryRewriter (a subclass of clang::RecursiveASTVisitor) for further processing.  In this case the processing is to rewrite `clang::ConditionalOperator' functions by adding a comment or sommething trivial in the expanded text.  Note that the printing options preserve comments from the original macros.
Partially working LibTooling example
The following code works up to the point where I attempt to ParseAST.  At that poing the clang::Preprocessor fails to
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "clang/Parse/ParseAST.h"
#include "clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h"
#include "clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h"
#include "llvm/TargetParser/Triple.h"
#include "llvm/TargetParser/Host.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"
#include "clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h"

class MyASTVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<MyASTVisitor> {
public:
    MyASTVisitor(clang::ASTContext &Context, clang::Rewriter &R)
        : Context(Context)
        , Rewriter(R)
    {}

    bool VisitStmt(clang::Stmt *S) const {
        // Example: Replace all return statements with a comment
        if (clang::isa<clang::ReturnStmt>(S)) {
            clang::SourceLocation Start = S->getBeginLoc();
            clang::SourceLocation End = S->getEndLoc();
            Rewriter.ReplaceText(clang::SourceRange(Start, End), "// Rewritten return statement");
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool VisitConditionalOperator(const clang::ConditionalOperator *CO) const {
        // Check if CO originated from a macro expansion
        if (CO->getBeginLoc().isMacroID()) {
            // Apply your custom logic to rewrite the ternary expression
            // Example: Replace ternary with a simple binary expression
            //std::string replacement = std::string("(") +
            //  CO->getCond()->getStmtClassName() +
            //    " ? " + CO->getTrueExpr()->getStmtClassName() +
            //    " : " + CO->getFalseExpr()->getStmtClassName() + ")";
            Rewriter.ReplaceText(CO->getSourceRange(), /*replacement*/"");
        }
        // Continue traversal
        return true;
    }

    // Return 'true' ('false' is default) to traverse AST in 'post-order'.
    // without this the rewrites will be corrupted due to overlaps.
    static bool shouldTraversePostOrder() {
        return true;
    }

private:
    clang::ASTContext &Context;
    clang::Rewriter &Rewriter;
};

// MyASTConsumer consumes AST and applies the visitor to it.
class MyASTConsumer : public clang::ASTConsumer {
public:
    // Constructor - initializes the visitor with the AST
    // context and rewriter.
    MyASTConsumer(clang::ASTContext &Context, clang::Rewriter &R)
        : Visitor(Context, R)
    {}

    // HandleTranslationUnit is called when the entire translation
    // unit has been parsed. It starts the traversal of the AST
    // using the visitor.
    void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext &Context) override {
        Visitor.TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
    }
private:
    // Visitor instance that will traverse and modify the AST.
    MyASTVisitor Visitor;
};

class MyFrontendAction : public clang::ASTFrontendAction {
public:
    // CreateASTConsumer is called to create an AST consumer for the given file.
    // It sets up the clang::rewriter with the source manager and language options.
    std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(
        clang::CompilerInstance &CI,
        llvm::StringRef InFile) override {
        Rewriter.setSourceMgr(
            CI.getSourceManager(),
            CI.getLangOpts());
        return std::make_unique<MyASTConsumer>(
            CI.getASTContext(), Rewriter);
    }

    // ExecuteAction is called to perform the main action of the frontend.
    // First, it preprocesses the input code, then it creates a new
    // CompilerInstance to parse the preprocessed code, and outputs the
    // rewritten code.
    void ExecuteAction() override {
        auto &PP = getCompilerInstance().getPreprocessor();
        PP.PrintStats();

        // use preprocessor options to minimize changes to the code.
        // in particular, we need to preserve blank lines, comments
        // and fully recursive macro expansions.
        clang::PreprocessorOutputOptions PPO;
        PPO.ShowCPP = true;                 // Print normal preprocessed output.
        PPO.ShowComments = true;            // Show comments.
        PPO.ShowLineMarkers = true;         // Show #line markers. (keep blank lines)
        PPO.UseLineDirectives = true;       // Use #line instead of GCC-style # N.
        PPO.ShowMacroComments = true;       // Show comments, even in macros.
        PPO.ShowMacros = true;              // Print macro definitions.
        PPO.ShowIncludeDirectives = false;  // Print includes, imports etc. within preprocessed output.
        PPO.RewriteIncludes = false;        // Preprocess include directives only.
        PPO.RewriteImports  = false;        // Include contents of transitively-imported modules.
        PPO.MinimizeWhitespace = false;     // Ignore whitespace from input.
        PPO.DirectivesOnly = false;         // Process directives but do not expand macros.
        PPO.KeepSystemIncludes = true;      // Do not expand system headers.

        // Preprocess the input code and store it in a string.
        std::string PreprocessedCode;
        llvm::raw_string_ostream OS(PreprocessedCode);
        clang::DoPrintPreprocessedInput(PP, &OS, PPO);
        OS.flush();

        // Filter out #line markers using std::ranges
        std::istringstream inputStream(PreprocessedCode);
        std::ostringstream tempStream;

        // gcc or msvc line markers supported
        static std::regex gLineMarkerPattern(
            R"(^#\s*(line\s*)?\d+\s+\"[^\"]+\".*)");

        // strip leading line markers - much easier to recognize the GCC format
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(inputStream, line)) {
            if (!std::regex_match(line, gLineMarkerPattern)) {
                tempStream << line << "\n";
                llvm::outs() << line << "\n";
            } else {
                llvm::outs() << "removed: " << line << "\n";
            }
        }

        // Create a memory buffer from the preprocessed code
        auto Buffer = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(
            tempStream.str(), "<preprocessed>");

        // Create a new CompilerInstance to parse the memory buffer
        clang::CompilerInstance CI;
        CI.createDiagnostics();

        // Set up target options for the new CompilerInstance.
        const auto TargetOpts = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
        TargetOpts->Triple = llvm::Triple::normalize(
            llvm::sys::getProcessTriple());
        CI.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(
            CI.getDiagnostics(), TargetOpts));

        // Create file manager and source manager for the new CompilerInstance.
        CI.createFileManager();
        CI.createSourceManager(CI.getFileManager());

        // Create a file ID for the memory buffer and set it as the main file.
        const auto FileID = CI.getSourceManager().createFileID(std::move(Buffer));
        CI.getSourceManager().setMainFileID(FileID);

        // Create a freshly minted preprocessor for the entire
        // translation unit and enter the main source file.
        CI.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
        CI.getPreprocessor().EnterMainSourceFile();
        CI.createASTContext();

        // Parse the AST from the preprocessed code.
        // This should initiate the Visitor callbacks
        // to rewrite the preprocessed code.
        // =====================================================
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP: THE FOLLOWING CALL RAISES
        // A PREPROCESSOR ASSERTION ERROR WHEN UNDER THE COVERS
        // IT CALLS 'Preprocessor::EnterMainSourceFile()'
        // assert(NumEnteredSourceFiles == 0 &&
        //    "Cannot reenter the main file!");
        // AT THIS TIME NumEnteredSourceFiles is 2.
        // =====================================================
        ParseAST(CI.getPreprocessor(),
            nullptr, CI.getASTContext());

        // Output the final rewritten code
        if (const clang::RewriteBuffer *RewriteBuf =
            Rewriter.getRewriteBufferFor(CI.getSourceManager().getMainFileID())) {
            llvm::outs() << std::string(RewriteBuf->begin(), RewriteBuf->end());
        }
    }

private:
    clang::Rewriter Rewriter;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
        if (file) {
            std::stringstream buffer;
            buffer << file.rdbuf();
            std::string code = buffer.str();
            clang::tooling::runToolOnCode(std::make_unique<MyFrontendAction>(), code, argv[1]);
        } else {
            llvm::errs() << "Error: Cannot open file " << argv[1] << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        llvm::errs() << "Usage: reparse <source-file>\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

Tool output
The following output is produced by running the tool with c:\temp\test2.c -- as the arguments.  The preprocessed output looks correct (ignore the removed: lines, as these are not put in the preprocessed clang::MemoryBuffer) and include fully expanded macros.
The problem occurs while entering clang::ParseAST().  See the code comments above for the surrounding details.
removed: #line 1 "C:\\temp\\test2.c"
removed: #line 1 "<built-in>"
removed: #line 1 "<command line>"
removed: #line 1 "<built-in>"
removed: #line 1 "C:\\temp\\test2.c"
#include <stdio.h> /* clang -E -fkeep-system-includes */
removed: #line 1 "C:\\temp\\test2.c"

removed: #line 2 "C:\\temp\\test2.c"

#define TWO (2) /* object like macro*/
#define THREE() (3) /* function like macro with 0 args*/
#define FOUR() (4) /* function like macro with 0 args*/
#define NUMSQUARED(x) ((x)*(x)) /* function like macro with 1 arg*/
#define MIN(a,b) (((a) <= (b/*COMMENTb1*/)) ? (a) : (b/*COMMENTb2*/))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define FUNC_MACRO(x) ((x) + 1)
#define NESTED_MACRO(a,b) (FUNC_MACRO(a) + NUMSQUARED(b) + FUNC_MACRO(FOUR()) + TWO + THREE())
#define DEFINE_FUNC(name) int name(int val) { int v1 = val + 1; return v1; }





// stamp out 'macroFooFn' functionDecl.
int macroFooFn(int val) { int v1 = val + 1; return v1; }

// stamp out 'macroBarFn(..)' functionDecl.
int macroBarFn(int val) { int v1 = val + 1; return v1; }

/* Main function comment */
int main() {
    // test1
    int a = (((1) + 1) + ((2)*(2)) /* function like macro with 1 arg*/ + (((4) /* function like macro with 0 args*/) + 1) + (2) /* object like macro*/ + (3) /* function like macro with 0 args*/);

    // test2
    int b = (((1) <= ((2) /* object like macro*//*COMMENTb1*/)) ? (1) : ((2) /* object like macro*//*COMMENTb2*/)); // trailing comment

    // test3
    int c = (((1) <= (2/*COMMENTb1*/)) ? (1) : (2/*COMMENTb2*/));

    // test4
    int d = (((1) <= ((3) /* function like macro with 0 args*//*COMMENTb1*/)) ? (1) : ((3) /* function like macro with 0 args*//*COMMENTb2*/));

    // test5
    int f = (((1) <= (((3)*(3)) /* function like macro with 1 arg*//*COMMENTb1*/)) ? (1) : (((3)*(3)) /* function like macro with 1 arg*//*COMMENTb2*/));

    // test6
    int g = ((((((1) > (2)) ? (1) : (2))) <= (3/*COMMENTb1*/)) ? ((((1) > (2)) ? (1) : (2))) : (3/*COMMENTb2*/));

    // test7
    int h = (a > 3) ? 4 : 5 /*comment*/;

    // test functionDecl macro expansion
    int nine = macroFooFn(8);

    // test functionDecl macro expansion
    int ten = macroBarFn(9);

    // return from main.
    return 1;
}
Assertion failed: NumEnteredSourceFiles == 0 && "Cannot reenter the main file!", file C:\tools\llvm-project\clang\lib\Lex\Preprocessor.cpp, line 547


If I understand, you could do this simply by saving the preprocessor output to a temporary file and then parsing that into an AST in a separate tool invocation.  So is the essence of the question how to effectively do that but in a single process?

@ScottMcPeak - Effectively yes (however I would need to strip the # 1 "<built-in>" 1 type lines from the start to keep the line numbers intact, BTW I totally got the macro expansions (even with comments intact) working after quite a bit trial and error and debugging clang source.  I don't think it should be necessary to write the expanded text to an intermediate file as I was under the impression that the clang::Preprocessor through the clang::PPCallbacks would automatically expand the tokens per my clang::PreprocessorOutputOptions - I need to tweak the question to make these options clearer

@ScottMcPeak thanks for pointing out the output errors - copied wrong output buffers.. just fixed it.

@ScottMcPeak - I'm much closer to a working solution now - I think I just need some help with the innards of the PreprocessAndRewriteAction::ExecuteAction after I stream the output to llvm::outs - I probably need to get it into the rewriter or something similar so I can pass it on to the TernaryRewriter.

@ScottMcPeak - Hi Scott, I was wondering if you had any idea how how to get past that last hurdle.  I've gotten the code fully expanded and stripped of all the leading line marker (GCC or otherwise) - but when I attempt to PP.EnterMainSourceFile() prior to parsing the AST with the expanded tokes I receive "Cannot reenter the main file!" - the surrounding comment is "We do not allow the preprocessor to reenter the main file.  Doing so will cause FileID's to accumulate information from both runs (e.g. #line information) and predefined macros aren't guaranteed to be set properly. Any ideas?

Just a guess, but maybe you have to create a new ASTContext and (with it) new SourceManager?  The system needs a way to distinguish the files it saw during initial preprocessing from those it is seeing on the second pass, and I think that's primarily done with those classes.  But you're well outside what I've tried to do!

@ScottMcPeak thanks! I'm actually trying that now - tried and failed using clang::MemoryBuffer containing the expanded tokens (complained about requiring a null at the end of a buffer) - trying to use a temporary file instead... I'll keep you posted ...

@ScottMcPeak - I am down to one little problem that I cannot fix - I simplified the question considerably (removing the PPCallbacks) and isolated the problem to just 1 point of contention - where assert(NumEnteredSourceFiles == 0 && "Cannot reenter the main file!");  At this time NumEnteredSourceFiles is 2 and should be 0 in order for me to succeed with the ParseAST - or at least get a bit further.
